# JavaScript JSON Syntax Error: Unrecognized Expression

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use jQuery to iterate through the objects in this JSON expression:

```
[
    {
        "value": 609,
        "label": "Wyandotte, MI"
    },
    {
        "value": 3141,
        "label": "Wilmington, NC"
    }
]
```

Such that each object consists of two properties, value and label.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(data).each(function () {
     alert('value: ' + this.value + ' label: ' + this.label);
});
```

But I keep getting an error:
**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression**

Can anyone help?

**Edit:**

The data variable in the example was arbitrary. What is actually happening is I'm getting an array of objects something like this:

```
data =
[
    locations: "[{"value":5626,"label":"Bensenville, IL"}]",
    notes: "Sample note"
]
```

Then I call `data = JSON.parse(data);`

And then I perform the iteration on `data.locations`, which is producing the error.

**Edit (again):**

https://jsfiddle.net/e2p7gdod/

I keep trying to reproduce what I'm seeing.

This is how I'm producing my return result:

```
public JsonResult Foo()
{
    var data = new JObject();
    data["locations"] = "[{'value': 609,'label': 'Wyandotte, MI'},{'value': 3141,'label': 'Wilmington, NC'}]";
    data["supervisor"] = "John Doe";
    data["notes"] = "Sample note";

    return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Comment: Your code as posted does not produce the error.  Exactly what happens before your `.each()` call? Where does `data` get its value?

Comment: Works fine as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/yk4wb7dv/ (assuming your array is `data`)

Comment: The `data` in your `Edit` is invalid syntax. When you have keys and values, they have to be in an object, not an array. It should be `data = { locations: ..., notes: "Sample note" }`

Comment: And if you're going to pass it to `JSON.parse`, the value of `data` should be a string, not an array.

Comment: The JSON is invalid. Strings in JSON have to be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand. Use `JSON.stringify()` on an object.

Comment: Or in C#, use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`

Comment: I am using JSON.SerializeObject(), but I wanted to show what JSON.SerializeObject() is returning for me. It's actually [{"value":3389,"label":"Chicago, IL"}] like that. The city is in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to put a JSON object in `data.locations`, but you have the syntax wrong. Strings in JSON must be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes.

```
public JsonResult Foo()
{
    var data = new JObject();
    data["locations"] = "[{\"value\": 609,\"label\": \"Wyandotte, MI\"},{\"value\": 3141,\"label\": \"Wilmington, NC\"}]";
    data["supervisor"] = "John Doe";
    data["notes"] = "Sample note";

    return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

Then in the Javascript, when you want to iterate over it, you need to call `JSON.parse(data.locations)`:

```
var locations = JSON.parse(data.locations);
$.each(locations, function() {
    alert('value: ' + this.value + ' label: ' + this.label);
});
```

Comment: The second part was the problem. I was calling JSON.parse on the data and then calling $(data.divisions).each(...) but I was not calling $(JSON.parse(data.divisions)).each()!!! Thank you thank you thank you! :-)

Comment: Why are you putting JSON into `data["locations"]` in the first place? Why not just put a C# array of objects there?

Answer (score 1):

That should be the static version of `each`, passing the array (faster than wrapping the array in a jQuery object, just to iterate over it):

```
$.each(data, function () {
     alert('value: ' + this.value + ' label: ' + this.label);
});
```

Note: Your current code does not give that error and appears to work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/yk4wb7dv/

Have you included JQuery etc?

Comment: Probably better, but the code as posted won't cause the error reported.

Comment: @Pointy: `$(data)` probably would cause that error if `data` is his object as I suspect.

Comment: Well the OP *says* that `data` is an array. If that's the case, then jQuery will just wrap itself around the array.

Comment: I've always done function(index, item) { ... } and then referenced item in the block.  "this" handling in JS scares me. :)

Comment: @Fiid: You can do that too. No need to be afraid of `this` though :)

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie, I'm still not able to figure out the problem. I updated my question with a little more detail about what's happening.